# Error Unexpected type required: variable found: value

Tags: java

Estoy trabajando con ArrayList tipo clase.
Mi clase se llama empleado
y estoy buscando ordenarlos de sueldo de mayor a menor con el método burbuja

```
ArrayList<empleado> lista = new ArrayList();


empleado aux = new empleado();

public void order(){
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < lista.size(); j++) {
            if(lista.get(i).sueldoPagar() < lista.get(j).sueldoPagar()){
                aux = lista.get(i);
                **lista.get(i) = lista.get(j);
                lista.get(j) = aux ;**
            }
        }
    }
}
```

El error se presenta en estas dos líneas:

```
lista.get(i) = lista.get(j);
lista.get(j) = aux
```

Unexpected type required: variable found: value

Y no da opciones.

Comment: pon tu clase empleado por favor y todo lo demás que se necesite para que compile, es decir para hacer un [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas asignando valor a un metodo void - `lista.get(i)` a esto no le puedes asignar valor.

Esto funciona así:

```
lista.add(i, lista.get(j));

lista.add(j, aux );
```

Mira [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)